# Java Selenium Chromedriver webdriver as fast as possible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am connecting a standalone program to a website, and I have to read some pages of the website. For first, I used Jsoup, but with this I discovered that some informations that I need are loaded after page load, so I searched for webdrivers. (I am not looking for images or something big, my content are all textual)

Now, i found the ChromeDriver, but it is too slow for my case because it has a lot of options and features. 
In my case I need just a step more than the Jsoup possibilities. 
It is possible to disable the best part of ChromeDriver options and features to reach this goal?

For example, i saw plugin disabling, but is one by one and is not for every chrome browser on every pc. I didn't found an option like "plugin.disable-all".

Furthermore,in this way I cannot open more than a few instance of chromedriver. In this moment, every instance of the chromedriver is opening a Google Chrome Helper that uses 100Mb of ram.

Hope all is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) might be enough for your needs. It does support *some* Javascript.

It can be used [with Webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver). But might as well be enough [on its own](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html#Finding_a_specific_element)

Comment: Wow. I am trying it. I hope that the website is all readable with this. I'll check as answered if it works.

Comment: It is official, works as I need. And, in my code, the performance is more than doubled. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To make your webdriver run faster (but not ***that*** much faster), you can run the driver in Headless mode. See [these](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/) [articles](https://thefriendlytester.co.uk/2017/04/new-headless-chrome-with-selenium.html) for a tutorial on how to go into Headless mode for Chrome.

Before starting the driver, add the `--headless` argument to `ChromeOptions`.

Headless mode can speed up your automation by not rendering the browser window, but keep in mind that doing a straight HTTP GET with JSoup would always be faster.

My advice would be to reverse engineer the page a bit more, and see if you can figure out how to query directly whatever the (presumably AJAX) calls are putting on the page. If you can treat those specific requests as an API and only query for exactly what you want, you will be able to get results faster than with browser automation through Selenium.

Comment: The headless option was just in use, but as you said is not too much more fast. As reguard the second part, it is interesting but takes a lot of time to understand how can I do it.